# Delete / trash posts in Wordpress front-end using ajax not work

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I tried to add a "trash this" to each wordpress posts, the trash link goes like:
php:

```
    <?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce('my_delete_post_nonce') ?>
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=my_delete_post&id=' . get_the_ID() . '&nonce=' . $nonce ) ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID() ?>" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" class="delete-post"><?php _e( 'Trash', 'my-theme' ); ?></a>
```

the out put link is:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_delete_post&id=1099&nonce=83171bb4b7
```

and the "my_delete_post" action in functions.php goes like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete_post', 'my_delete_post' );
function my_delete_post(){
    $permission = check_ajax_referer( 'my_delete_post_nonce', 'nonce', false );
    if( $permission == false ) {
        echo 'error';
    }
    else {
        wp_trash_post( $_REQUEST['id'] );
        echo 'success';
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

It works, and when click the link, and it will redirect to a page with "success" text.

So I  add ajax to js file tried to make it better, the js part goes like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //delete post ajax
    $( '.delete-post' ).click( function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var nonce = $(this).data('nonce');
        var article = $(this).parents('article');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                action: 'my_delete_post',
                nonce: nonce,
                id: id
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                    article.slideUp( function(){
                        article.remove();
                    });
                    console.log("deleteed");
            }
        })
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

The article will be "slide up" and gone after I click trash link, but the actual post is still there, it will comes out when I reload the page.

**The strange thing is: click the trash link - not work, open the link in new tab - trash success!**

Is there something wrong with my Ajax part code? seems the php action "wp_trash_post" not executed in ajax.

please help.

Comment: https://www.dorcode.com/questions/130/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-page

Comment: @Gulshan no it didn’t help